# Generate Series within Group

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have data like:

```
pkey, category, group_id
1,       a,      NULL
2,       a,      NULL
3,       a,      NULL
4,       b,      NULL
5,       b,      NULL
6,       b,      NULL
```

how can I replace the nulls with a serial that resets for each category?

to get:

```
pkey, category, group_id
1,       a,      1
2,       a,      2
3,       a,      3
4,       b,      1
5,       b,      2
6,       b,      3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by category order by pkey) as group_id
from t;
```

You can include this in an `update` if you actually want to change the data:

```
update t
    set group_id = tt.new_group_id
    from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by category order by pkey) as new_group_id
          from t
         ) tt
    where tt.pkey = t.pkey;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    pkey,
    category,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY pkey) group_id
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    pkey;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: awesome I was trying to use `GROUP BY` and `SERIAL` and getting no where

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley Sadly, if you go into the fields of software and data engineering, you will often feel this way `:-|`.